# group by with (-) operator in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query like this below. There is (`-`) operator = `(AA.SOURCE_CREDIT - BB.SOURCE_DEBIT / 1.1)`. I want to group by BR.AREA_ID. Just BR.AREA_ID. But it gave me error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

And I have to add AA.SOURCE_CREDIT and BB.SOURCE_DEBIT in group by. But the result becoming not what I want. Just AREA_ID that I want.

```
 SELECT   'SALES EU' AS DESCRIPTION,
           (AA.SOURCE_CREDIT - BB.SOURCE_DEBIT / 1.1) AS amount,
           BR.AREA_ID
    FROM            VI_REPORT_BK_PENJUALAN BK
                 JOIN
                    MST_BRANCH BR
                 ON BR.BRANCH_ID = BK.BRANCH_ID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (SELECT   JH.JOURNAL_NO, JD.SOURCE_CREDIT
                    FROM         TRX_JOURNAL_GL_HEADER JH
                              JOIN
                                 TRX_JOURNAL_GL_DETAIL JD
                              ON JH.JOURNAL_NO = jd.JOURNAL_NO
                           JOIN
                              TRX_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION DC
                           ON DC.DELIVERY_NO = JH.DOCUMENT_NO
                   WHERE   JD.SOURCE_TYPE = '40100000') AA
              ON (AA.JOURNAL_NO = BK.JOURNAL_NO)
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
              (SELECT   JH.JOURNAL_NO, JD.SOURCE_DEBIT
                 FROM         TRX_JOURNAL_GL_HEADER JH
                           JOIN
                              TRX_JOURNAL_GL_DETAIL JD
                           ON JH.JOURNAL_NO = jd.JOURNAL_NO
                        JOIN
                           TRX_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION DC
                        ON DC.DELIVERY_NO = JH.DOCUMENT_NO
                WHERE   JD.SOURCE_TYPE = '40502002') BB
           ON (BB.JOURNAL_NO = BK.JOURNAL_NO)
GROUP BY   BR.AREA_ID, AA.SOURCE_CREDIT, BB.SOURCE_DEBIT
```

I already try to make group by inside the subs-query. But still not work. I'm browsing also in google but I didn't find the case like my case.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: so what I have to used in my case? or give me any idea  of keyword to find about my case to explore it. thank you so much

Comment: If a BR.AREA_ID has several (different) AA.SOURCE_CREDIT, BB.SOURCE_DEBIT values after the JOIN, what do you want to do with them? Display them all, or sum them?

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I found already the answer that i need below.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf there are more rows than one to each row, what do you expect the query gives back?
Example:

```
AREA_ID | AA.SOURCE_CREDIT | BB.SOURCE_DEBIT
   1    |      100         |       50
   1    |       70         |       50
```

It you are sure there is only one row for each area id, so you could use SUM, MAX, AVG or anything else.

```
SELECT   'SALES EU' AS DESCRIPTION,
           (MAX(AA.SOURCE_CREDIT) - MAX(BB.SOURCE_DEBIT) / 1.1) AS amount,
           BR.AREA_ID
...
```

If there could be more results you should decide, what Aggregate function fits best.

Comment: hooooo thank you sooo much. In my case only one row. this is what I want. thank you so much :D